# Arithmetic using vue expression produces a string instead of adding

Tags: vue.js

I have some data that i am displaying  using vue js and it looks like this

```
"stayRooms" : [
                        {
                                "value" : "",
                                "singleBed" : "1",
                                "doublebed" : "0",
                                "largeBed" : "0",
                                "extraLargeBed" : "0",
                                "bunkBed" : "0",
                                "sofaBed" : "0",
                                "futonMat" : "0",
                                "roomTypes" : "apartment",
                                "bathroomType" : "private",
                                "numberofRoomsofThisType" : "77",
                                "room_name" : "KIng Room",
                                "price_per_night" : "0"
                        },
                        {
                                "value" : "",
                                "singleBed" : "1",
                                "doublebed" : "1",
                                "largeBed" : "0",
                                "extraLargeBed" : "0",
                                "bunkBed" : "0",
                                "sofaBed" : "0",
                                "futonMat" : "0",
                                "roomTypes" : "family",
                                "bathroomType" : "private",
                                "numberofRoomsofThisType" : "77",
                                "room_name" : "Queen Room Deluxe",
                                "price_per_night" : "0"
                        }
                ],
```

and displaying it like this

```
<tr v-for="room in all_available_rooms" :key="room.value">
     <td>
       {{room.room_name}} <span class="badge badge-primary">{{room.roomTypes}}</span>
      </td>
        <td>
       {{ room.doublebed + room.largeBed + room.extraLargeBed + room.bunkBed + room.sofaBed + room.futonMat }}
      </td>
```

I want to add all the values in

```
{{ room.doublebed + room.largeBed + room.extraLargeBed + room.bunkBed + room.sofaBed + room.futonMat }}
```

and when i do, i get the value `1000000` and not 1. Is there a way i can make this add up normally without having to change the data type in mongodb?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prefix each property by `+` to convert it to a number like

```
{{ (+room.doublebed) + (+room.largeBed)+ ....}}
```

Comment: This works ``{{ (+room.singleBed) + (+room.doublebed) + (+room.largeBed) + (+room.extraLargeBed) + (+room.bunkBed) + (+room.sofaBed) + (+room.futonMat) }}`` How can i multiply the entire result of the addition by 2. In the app i am building, i am asuming a bed can sleep a maximum of two people therefore the need to multiple by two.

Comment: wrap them the addition result by `()` and multiply it by 2 `{{ ((+room.singleBed) + (+room.doublebed) + (+room.largeBed) + (+room.extraLargeBed) + (+room.bunkBed) + (+room.sofaBed) + (+room.futonMat))*2 }}`